# An error occurred TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object in Angular interceptor

Tags: javascript, angular, http, interceptor

Passing numeric data in the header gives this error. When changed to string the error is fixed. But can anyone explain what is the reason behind this in Angular interceptor?
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkDTq.png)

```
intercept(
req: HttpRequest<any>,
next: HttpHandler
): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
this.userDataService = this.injector.get(UserDataService);
const userData = this.userDataService.getUserDetails();
const tokenHeader = userData.userToken.token;
**const userIdHeader = userData.user.userId.toString();**
let authReq: any;

if (tokenHeader && userIdHeader) {
  authReq = req.clone({
    setHeaders: { Token: tokenHeader, UserId: userIdHeader }
  });
} else {
  authReq = req.clone({
    setHeaders: { Token: "no_token", UserId: "no_user" }
  });
}
return next.handle(authReq);
}
```

In here if I remove .toString() in the line marked with astrik which otherwise is of type number I get the error as in the image.

Comment: Add some code maybe

Comment: I have added the code for example @David